# Combine 2 rows give a new name and SUM their respective value display in a new column and take any of the row date

Tags: sql-server

Problem

```
Field Name     Field Value        date
Jak              10             08/08/2020
Danz             15             08/08/2020    
Rob              20             08/08/2020
```

Result should be: create new column for New Field Name and New column for SUM field value.

```
Field Name  Field Value  date       New Col  NewFieldValue    Date
Jak             10      08/08/2020     Mat        45        08/08/2020
Danz            15      08/08/2020    
Rob             20      08/08/2020
```

Comment: Please have a go and only post a question when stuck. We're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: Hint: `SourceTable ST LEFT JOIN DerivedTable DT ON ST.RowNumber = DT.RowNumber AND ST.[Date] = DT.[Date]`

Comment: PS: What if there is a different `Date` other than `2020-08-08`? How it should looks like? and does the `NewCol` always be `'Mat'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't write the code for you because you won't learn anything, instead I'll give you some points to go with:

- Generate a row number based on `[Date]` column using a subquery.
- Generate a row number based on `[Date]` column and the `SUM()` of `FieldValue` column grouped by `Date` column using another subquery.
- `LEFT JOIN` both on `RowNumber` and `[Date]` columns.